# Stata: Deleting duplicates based on dates

Tags: sorting, duplicates, stata

My dataset consists of a number of variables:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(v1 v2) str11 Date float(v4 v5 v6 v7 v8)
1 2 "15-aug-2016" 1 1 1 1  1
1 2 "07-may-2015" 1 1 1 1 50
1 2 "07-may-2015" 1 1 1 1 88
1 2 "15-aug-2016" 1 1 1 1 29
end
```

The variable `date` is a date and time and is formatted as a datetime

`generate double date = date(Date,"DMY")`

My duplicates are the same for v1-v2-v4-v5-v6-v7 (as in the example), while v8 is different.

I need to delete duplicates based on v1-v2-v4-v5-v6-v7 and keep the one with the smallest date (here 07-may-2015).

I have tried without success:

1.

```
gsort -date
bysort v1 v2 v4 v5 v6 v7: generate dublet=_n
order dublet date
keep if dublet==1
drop dublet
```

--> Works for the first 25 rows or so, then keeps the wrong one a couple of times and then the right one again. (Seems to me, that the `bysort` command removes the sort done by `gsort`? Any knowing if that's correct?)

2. `bysort v1 v2 v4 v5 v6 v7 (date) : keep if _n == _N`

--> Obviously keeps the wrong one, since `Date` is not `-Date`. 
However, `-Date` is not an option - Stata writes: `- invalid name`

Comment: `bysort` certainly undoes your `gsort` in your code. As instead of keeping the last date you can keep the first, there is no need to negate any variable before sorting, either directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your second answer to `bysort v1 v2 v4 v5 v6 v7 (date) : keep if _n == 1` and that should give you what you're looking for.

Since in your data example there are duplicate dates (2 observations are May 7th 2015) you will get a random one of the observations with the minimum date.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the job.
And OK about the two with 07-may-2015!